# Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on array in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, many-to-many

Here is the content of my custom repository function for my entity Feed.

SearchController.php

```
$searches=$this->getDoctrine()-getRepository('UserBundle:User')->findPersonType(1);
```

Repository Function:

```
public function findPersonType($usertype)
    {
        $queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->addSelect("u")
            ->where('u.personType = :personType')
            ->setParameter('personType', $usertype);
        try {
            $query = $queryBuilder->getQuery();
            return $query->getResult();
        } catch (NonUniqueResultException $e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

When I try to use loop in mycontroller

```
foreach ($searches->getId() as $s) {

     echo '<pre>';
     print_r($s->getAccreditationdata());
     echo '<br>';

}
die;
```

I've got an error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on array

If I do like this way it is working fine:

```
foreach ($searches as $s) {

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($s->getId());
    echo '<br>';
}
die;
```

I get following user_ids: 12345, 1234567, 234567

**Now, for these user ids further I want to find there accreditations and sectors, Both have many to many relation in User Entity. So, How can I get multiple "sectors" and "accreditations" data of all these users in there list on search page?**

**Edit:**

Below is the User Entity Relation of sector and accreditation.

```
/**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="UserBundle\Entity\Sectors", inversedBy="user", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE")}
     * )
     */
    public $sectors;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="UserBundle\Entity\Accreditations", inversedBy="user" , cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE")}
     * )
     */
    public $accreditationdata;
```

Comment: Insteed of `print_r($s->getId());` call `print_r($s->getAccreditationdata());` in your working exmaple?

Answer (score 0):

If you have relation between "Search" Entity and "User" Entity you can do it like this

```
foreach ($searches as $s) {
echo '<pre>';
// Instead of print_r($s->getId());
// Try
print_r($s->getUser()->getSectors());
print_r($s->getUser()->getAccreditationdata());
echo '<br>';
}
die;
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't this code not work ? It is the same as yours but without "getId()" in the loop.

```
foreach ($searches as $s) {

     echo '<pre>';
     print_r($s->getAccreditationdata());
     echo '<br>';

}
die;
```

Comment: No, its doesn't as you had seen $searches has lots of data of so many users. I want to show list of users in search results and their multiple accreditation data in a table also each accrediations is dependent on sectors which also need to show in sectors column